# Wordpress Cake theme error in meta-functions.php line 1792

Tags: php, wordpress, function, themes

i've got an error on this line in this theme in file meta-functions.php.How to resolve this ?

```
$section_style[]    = 'padding-top:'. intval(
```

Comment: Please provide more info. It looks like a "Array to string conversion" error. Is the message you are getting?

Comment: Here is an error: https://pastebin.com/4WmG3atG

Comment: This a fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings. Please change your question title and here you will find ideas how to fix your error,           https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879675/problem-with-fatal-error-operator-not-supported-for-strings-in?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with: Fatal error: \[\] operator not supported for strings in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879675/problem-with-fatal-error-operator-not-supported-for-strings-in)