# Get around php 7.2 "[] operator not supported for strings" OR uninitialized variables?

Tags: php, php-7.2

This is not a duplicate.  My variable is not a string.  My variable doesnt exist yet.
I have seen the questions regarding variables that are init as strings:

```
$myvar = '';//now it's a string, an empty string.
$myvar[] = 'some thing';
[] operator not supported for strings //fine, ok, it dint typecast.
```

However, php 7.2 treats an unitialized variable as a string, apparently.

```
$myvar[] = 'some thing';
[] operator not supported for strings // $myvar isnt a string, tho. It's nothing.
```

Is there a way to get around this new strictness?  I've always liked php's relaxed way of dealing with un initialized vars, so this is aggravating.

I know that if I init as an array, it will work:

```
$myvar = array();
$myvar[] = 'some thing';
```

Comment: You need to look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54795437/9811969
It is not supported since 7.1

Comment: `$myvar = '';` isn't uninitialized. `$myvar = null;` perhaps.

Comment: I don't see the problem with uninitialized variables: https://3v4l.org/41kpJ

Comment: @kuh-chan it doesnt work on php 7.2 at WPEngine...

Comment: Guys... $myvar isnt a string, that's why this is not a dupe.

Comment: @DougCassidy PHP is quite clearly telling you that it **is** a string. If it were something else, the error message would indicate that