# Cant update theme pages using Page Builder

Tags: php, wordpress, php-5.6, php-7.2

We are currently migrating our site from php 5.6 to 7.2 as our hosts have set a fixed end of life for this.

We are using BeTheme and we can see that most features are intact, however when updating posts the site breaks when the muffin builder existing layouts, this largely is due to a

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in /XXXXX/wp-content/themes/XXXXX/functions/meta-functions.php

`$mfn_items[$newParentSectionID]['items'][] = $item;`

Any ideas to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when attempting to use the short array push syntax on a string.

For example, this

```
$foo = 'foo';
$foo[] = 'bar'; // ERROR!
```

It seems there are some issues with PHP 7 and code using the empty-index array push syntax.

To make it clear, these work fine in PHP 7+

```
$previouslyUndeclaredVariableName[] = 'value'; // creates an array and adds one entry

$emptyArray = []; // creates an array
$emptyArray[] = 'value'; // pushes in an entry
```

you need to edit your code.

like this

```
$mfn_items = array();
$mfn_items[$newParentSectionID]['items'][] = $item;
```

more details you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879675/problem-with-fatal-error-operator-not-supported-for-strings-in/5879729)

Comment: This works and the page submits, however the the associated existing layout is now broken. Any ideas?

Comment: I may need to look at.

Comment: Can you please provide site url or screenshots?

Comment: Theres no real error stack thats generated, just a broken / stripped layout

Comment: Can you please add new page for testing then check layout still broken or not?

Comment: Seems adding a new post also break the layout. I have a feeling that there could be a different encoding postmeta table.